# Populating input fields in a form via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using fullCalendar and am developing an approach to edit the events. I'm using the eventClick function to open a JQuery-UI form. I want to prepopulate the form with the current event details. I have the following code:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
   // Set variables for the clicked event
   e_title = calEvent.title;
   $("#e_title").val(e_title);
   ...
```

When I click on an event, the form fields are populated with "[object HTMLInputElement]" instead of the values. So, I know I'm pointing at the right elements of the form...just can't get the values in there. What do I need to change? Is "event.title" not providing the value of the title?

Thanks.

**Update:** Thanks for the comments. I spent some more time and have solved the issue. I did have the correct syntax. I just had it in the wrong place. Following is a snippet showing that I placed the code to update the input fields immediately following the open command. Thanks.

```
 eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    // Open the modal form to edit an event
    $('#edit-event').dialog('open');

    // Populate the fields with the current data
    $("#edit_title").val(calEvent.title);
    ...
```

Comment: So `#e_title` is the input element that shows `[object HTMLInputElement]`? You can see which properties the event object has in documentation: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: `'Is "event.title" not providing the value of the title'`, obviously not, otherwise you would have seen the values. Are you sure you shouldn't be using `event.target.title`

Comment: @adeneo: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/. `$("#e_title").val(e_title);` should work correctly, maybe the problem is with another field.

Comment: What gives `typeof event.title`? We cannot help you without additionnal information. Setting up a jsfiddle that isolates the issue would be best.